# imported variables has union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js, union-types

I created a custom hook in `nextjs` project to check if a specific container is visible in the viewport using `intersection observer`.

the hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const useIsTheorySectionCompleted = (options: IntersectionObserverInit) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cb = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
      const [entry] = entries;
      if (!isCompleted) {
        setIsCompleted(entry.isIntersecting);
      }
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(cb, options);
    if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef.current);

    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef.current);
    };
  }, [containerRef, isCompleted, options]);

  return [containerRef, isCompleted];
};

export default useIsTheorySectionCompleted;
```

The returned value `containerRef` is of type `MutableRefObject<null>`
[image]
and the other returned value is of type `boolean`
[image]

Now when I import those valus in a component, they suddenly have a union type of `<boolean | >`
[image]

[image]

and this creates an TS error when I want to use `containerRef` as `ref`
[image]

Comment: Needs to be a tuple; `return [containerRef, isCompleted] as const;`

Comment: See https://devtrium.com/posts/react-typescript-how-to-type-hooks#bonus-how-to-type-custom-hooks

Comment: @caTS that's the solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The return values need to be a tuple
`return [containerRef, isCompleted] as const;`

Thanks to @caTS for the help!